# GXT4 - Problem with the axis Y of the charts

Tags: java, charts, gwt, linechart, gxt

I'm in the process of implementing GXT 4 to display Line Charts based on the example:
https://examples.sencha.com/gxt/examples/#ExamplePlace:charts_linechart

I have a problem with the axis Y not showing me double values, see attached image.

For the example in image, I have a minimum of -0.75 and a max of 0.8. But the values displayed on the axis are "0" and "-0".

Can you help me solve this problem please.
Regards.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlsPj.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be using the default axis label provider, which is only displaying the integer value of the values.

Try creating a new label provider which uses your preferred level of precision and passing it to `yAxis.setLabelProvider(...)`. Just sending the string value of the number can be problematic since double values might be more precise than you want (for example, `0.300000000001` instead of `0.3`)

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your help, it works fine for the LineChart.
On the other hand for the RadarChart, I still have the same problem ... I tried an axis.setScaleLabelProvider (new LabelProvider <Number> () {...} but it didn't work.
do you have an idea please?
my code is inspired by the Sencha example below :
https://examples.sencha.com/gxt/examples/#ExamplePlace:charts_radarchart